# Confused about how to retrieve gridview row values

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a basic appalication that reads from a text file then splits  string values values by comma and finally add this values to a gridview as rows.This my code to achieve this and its works.

```
 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
 {
      string line;
      while ((line = reader.ReadLine())!=null)
      {
           liste.Add(line.Split(',')[0]);
      }
 }

 for (int i = 0; i < liste.Count; i++)
 {
      dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
      dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = liste[i];
 }
```

Gridview has two columns first one is checkbox and the other one is textbox column The problem is I need to get this row values from the gridview .But I am getting null pointer exception .So I have decided to check like this way

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
 {
      MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].ToString());
 }
```

and realized result are not as expected.Messagebox display this result

```
datagridviewtextboxcell {columnindex=1 rowindex=0}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is the result not as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing value property here

```
MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].ToString());
```

try this:

```
MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value == null ? "null" : dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Once the gridview populated from texfile.an empty rows added automatically. I think the reason was that as you guessed.How did you understand and is it possible to prevent this empy row from adding.I will accept your answer in a few minutes later

Comment: @digrev07, try `dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;` before you populate the grid. if AllowUserToAddRows = true, grid shows one more line for input, and RowCount is increased by 1